# How to build new widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to build new widget in the first page by click on button in the another page in flutter ?
I tried to build a method but it doesn't work !

Comment: share your code please

Comment: could you please elaborate your requirement.?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change something in first widget when a button in another widget is pressed then there are multiple ways of achieving that.

1. You can use callbacks
2. You can use ChangeNotifier

Below is the pseudocode to use callbacks to do something in first widget when button in second widget is pressed.
You can also look into the existing flutter widgets to understand how they pass data to parent widget.

```
Widget1 {

  Widget2(onButtonPressedCallback: () {
    // Add whatever you want to do here in widget1 when the button is pressed in widget2
  });

}



Widget2 {

  Widget2({required this.onButtonPressedCallback})

  Function() onButtonPressedCallback;

  // Call this function when button is pressed
  onButtonTap {
    onButtonPressedCallback();
  }
}
```